Removing Matching Pixels?
I'm using Gimp 3.0 and have two images: a background, and a composite of content placed on top of that background.  I want a result that is just "content" with all visible "background" removed (made transparent).
Manually selecting and erasing the background is not practical as the images are huge and complicated.
I tried "subtract" of layers but while that removes the background, it leaves the content a mess.
How do I do this?
Edit: Algorithmically, I'm looking for:
for every pixel in layer B:
   if pixelB == pixelA:
       pixelB = transparent


Presumably the compositing was done using some opacity mask (maybe expressed as an alpha channel in the content) that made the content's opacity vary-- perhaps opaque at the center, varying to transparent at the edges.  Given that, it seems to me there isn't a unique answer given the information you have.  For example, what if, at some pixel position, the background pixel is black and the composite pixel is 50% gray.  That could be the result of either white content at 50% opacity, or 50% gray content at 100% opacity, or anything in between-- there's no way of telling which.

That isn't the case I'm dealing with.  One image with transparent regions was overlayed on a background.  I have the background; I want to recover the overlay.  The images were stored lossless.

@BrianWhite ah I see, you have clarified completely what you are looking for in your latest edit.  Thank you!

@BrianWhite Are you attached to doing this in gimp?  I'd probably find it easier to write something in python:  read both images, do your little three line loop on the pixels, write the result image back out.

I've thought about it.  It could programmed as a Gimp extensions, too.  I just figured it might already exist somewhere.

You are not alone. Many people in GDSE have had the same dream during the last decade.I mean this:

"I have 2 photos of the same landscape. The first photo has an interesting foreground object and the second photo has only the same landscape background without the interesting foreground object. There should be a way to separate the interesting object by somehow subtracting the plain landscape. How do I do it?"
The dream continues. The beach is the common landscape and the tyre is the interesting foreground object. Both photos are inserted to the same GIMP document as layers.
Dreaming the needed process a while gives a solution:

Blending mode difference makes the common part exact black. One can select all black with zero tolerance and use that selection to delete the background. The selection (by magic wand) is expanded one pixel because there's an edge zone where the tyre and the background are mixed.

The result looks pretty good - solved!
It's only a dream, because in practice 2 separate photos of the same landscape are not identical. An actual tyre would at least make a shadow and everything moves in the nature, for example the sunlight. And keeping the camera 100,0000% stable between the shots is not at all easy. The subtraction worked only because the beach photo was the same in both layers and the tyre was inserted afterwards to one of them.
You can, of course, try the same. It works if the background happens to be the same shot and the foreground object is an overlay like in my example. If the shots are separate it works only in an incredibly lucky case when minor differences can be  compensated by using a small nonzero color selection tolerance.
Using the black area to mask off the unwanted part gives some room to adjust the background removal, but the basic fault (=nonidentical shots) of the whole idea stays. I'm afraid you must brush up the commonly used background removal methods.

One way to do it would be to put the two images as layers and use the "Difference" blending mode on the top one. (A)
This will make the exact same pixels black and any other one would be not black. (B)
Then take this information, convert it to black and white, make some level adjustments, and use it as a mask. (C)


A caveat is that you can have places in the subject that just happen to be the color of the background and will create holes, so you can have to deal with these, possibly by just painting them over in the created mask, or using a median blur or the sequence Generic > Erode, Generic > Dilate

Yeap. It is a probabilistic problem. Life is not perfect.
